Implementing Automation Test On ClaimCenter 8.0.7
I need to implement an automation test for ClaimCenter 8.0.7. I want to build test cases quickly and easily. From this need, I think about Guidewire Testing Framework that pre-builds test cases.

However, according to Guidewire documentation, this framework is only supported on Guidewire Cloud Platform (Elysian, Flaine, etc.). The only way is that I have to implement test cases from scratch by using Selenium library. As a question, Which program (Python, Gosu, Java, etc.) should I use to write test cases quickly as well as manage them easily?

Implementing test automation on such an old version of ClaimCenter won't allow you to use the GT Framework as you have already discovered. In the past I have seen some carriers use Selenium for automated regression testing (using the same ClaimCenter version as you) and it has usually been adequate. There are obviously other testing frameworks (both open source and licensed) you can experiment with and for your case you will need to evaluate each and figure out which one works best.
One thing to note if you have the chance to talk to someone who owns the Guidewire program at your carrier. ClaimCenter 8 is very old and it may be better to upgrade ClaimCenter to the Cloud (or most recent on-premise version). Because any effort you put into test automation on ClaimCenter 8 might need to be redone after ClaimCenter is upgraded.

Kimputing provides test automation framework called CenterTest which supports all Guidewire versions from v7 to the cloud. If you don't change the screens, you can even reuse the same test after the upgrade.
